# Flutter admob bidding Applovin no ad issue

Tags: flutter, admob, waterfall, mobile-ad-mediation, applovin

I have a Flutter app with ads from Admob. Normal ads are working fine. I am trying to use admob bidding to get ads from third-party ad sources. I have added Applovin as an ad source to my Admob account and the required SDK to my Flutter app for android (I am only targeting AndroidAndroid). On ad inspector, applovin appears on the adapters list. From the ad inspector, I can request ads from Applovin. However, it does not appear as a bidder on the individual ad's bidder list. For all the requested ads, the only bidder (and the winning bid) is Admob Network.

To force getting ads from applovin, I tried using the single ad source feature of the ad inspector. And this is the error I am getting:

`LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No fill., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: [], loadedAdapterResponseInfo: null), responseExtras: {})`

What could be the problem here? I would greatly appreciate any help.

I have contacted applovin support and have been told that they have not gotten any bidding request from Google on behalf of my account.
I doubled checked ad unit mappings. Applovin is listed under the bidding sources on my admob account.
I have tested both release and test builds with vpn from EEA, USA and non-EEA.